# Apply filter to path in svg

Tags: svg

I have a triangle drawn with `path`:

[image: Original triangle: Green.]

I want to apply a filter to it:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.2" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="gradA0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="50.000000" y1="50.000000" x2="130.000000" y2="210.000000">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#ff0000"/>
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#000000"/>
        </linearGradient>

        <path id="pathA0" d="M 50.000000,50.000000 L 250.000000,150.000000 50.000000,250.000000 Z" fill="url(#gradA0)"/>
        
        <filter id="default0">
            <feImage xlink:href="#pathA0" result="layerA0" x="0" y="0"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
    
    <path d="M 50.000000,50.000000 L 250.000000,150.000000 50.000000,250.000000 Z" filter="url(#default0)"/>
</svg>
```

And the result:

[image: Result triangle: Red-black fade and clipped.]

Why the applied image is clipped? How to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't sized your SVG element. SVG has no implicit sizing, if you don't provide it, then browsers are free to give you whatever size they want. Firefox is 100px by 100px I think..

Update:
You also haven't sized your feImage (SVG is not very forgiving). This version works:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.2" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="1000px" height="800px" viewBox="0 0 1000 800">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="gradA0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="50.000000" y1="50.000000" x2="130.000000" y2="210.000000">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#ff0000"/>
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#000000"/>
        </linearGradient>

        <path id="pathA0" d="M 50.000000,50.000000 L 250.000000,150.000000 50.000000,250.000000 Z" fill="url(#gradA0)"/>

        <filter id="default0">
            <feImage xlink:href="#pathA0" result="layerA0" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>

    <path d="M 50.000000,50.000000 L 250.000000,150.000000 50.000000,250.000000 Z" filter="url(#default0)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Which element? The top level `svg` is 100% by default. I tried to set `width` and `height` on `filter` and `image` but this have no effect.

Comment: Top level SVG is actually not 100% by default - you need to explicitly add width="100%" and height="100%" to it (or via CSS)

Comment: Anyway doesn't work for my example. As you can see the first triangle renders ok. The problem is with the second only - it seems that the image filter is clipped.